# What is really happening in this command?

Tags: io-redirection, cat, here-string

When I use the command `cat <<< Hey > text.txt text.txt` I expect it to write "Hey" in the file text.txt and then display the file. But there is no output. How is bash interpreting it actually?

Command and its output:

```
$ cat <<< Hey > text.txt text.txt
$ cat text.txt
$
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe it will make sense if you rearrange the redirections a bit:

```
<<< Hey > text.txt cat text.txt
```

`Hey` is sent to stdin of cat, as a herestring. `text.txt` is opened for writing, and truncated. So if any text were in it, it would be gone.

`cat` is executed with the argument `text.txt`. Since a file was provided as an argument, it ignores stdin, so the `Hey` is unused. `text.txt` was truncated, so when `cat` runs through `text.txt` the argument, there's nothing to output, so `text.txt`, which is the stdout of `cat` via redirection, continues to remain empty.

Comment: And the “obvious” fix, `<<< Hey > text.txt cat - text.txt`, doesn’t work at least with GNU `cat` because it refuses to process an input file which is also its output file.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `-` can be used to tell cat to still read from stdin after reading a file but it still wouldn't work in this case since OP wants to read from the same file they are attempting to write to.

Comment: So basically, whenever a file is passed for reading, cat will always ignore the STDIN?

Comment: @sh.3.ll: unless `-` is used.